# React render is missing semicolon

Tags: reactjs

can you please explain why I'm getting this error when it's not required to include a semicolon there?

Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
SyntaxError: /Users/admin/react-tutorialmike/src/App.js: Missing semicolon (38:8)

36 | }
37 |

> 38 | render() {
> |         ^
> 39 |     const { characters } = this.state
> 40 |
> 41 |     return (

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Table from './table'


class App extends Component {
    state = {
      characters: [
        {
            name: 'Jan',
            job: 'Kucharz',
          },
          {
            name: 'Maciek',
            job: 'Rolnik',
          },
          {
            name: 'Dawid',
            job: 'Designer',
          },
          {
            name: 'Dennis',
            job: 'CEO',
          },
      ],
    }
};

removeCharacter = index => {
    const { characters } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        characters: characters.filter((character, i) => { 
            return i !== index;
        })
    })
}

render() {
    const { characters } = this.state
  
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Table characterData={characters} removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter} />
      </div>
    )
  }

export default App
```

Comment: It's not required by React or JavaScript, but it's (probably) required by a linter that is being used in your project. Are you using ESLint by chance?

Comment: If this is a new project, I would recommend using functional components with hooks instead of class-based components.

Answer (score 2):

`render` needs to be inside the `class`, as does `removeCharacter` (given that you're using `this`). You also seem to be missing a `constructor` wrapper around your state setting.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      characters: [
        {
            name: 'Jan',
            job: 'Kucharz',
          },
          {
            name: 'Maciek',
            job: 'Rolnik',
          },
          {
            name: 'Dawid',
            job: 'Designer',
          },
          {
            name: 'Dennis',
            job: 'CEO',
          },
      ],
    };
  }

  removeCharacter(index): {
    const { characters } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        characters: characters.filter((character, i) => { 
            return i !== index;
        })
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { characters } = this.state;
  
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Table characterData={characters} removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```